# Prevent adding records through navigation properties in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository

In implementing the CRUD operations through the repository pattern, I realized that being able to add records through the navigation properties defeats the purpose of forcing all operations to go through the data layer. For example, let's say I have some business logic in my .Insert method and I want all inserts of students to go through my Insert method:

```
studentRepository.Insert(student);
```

The issue is, there's nothing preventing me from adding a student through the Students navigation property from the Course entity:

```
Course.Students.Add(student);
```

thereby bypassing my business logic and breaking the layered pattern.

Is there something I'm missing here?